# Theme related WSOD in backend for other users

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wsod

After trying out all typical solutions for wordpress wsods, I am out of ideas.

I migrated my website from wordpress.com to a self-hosted solution using all-in-one-wp-migration, which looked to work fine, until a coworker wanted to use the backend and got wsod.

After going through all the suggestions for fixing wsods and a few of my own, namely:

- checking every single plugin used
- checking memory (980m should be enough?)
- deleting and reinstating all saved accounts
- scrubbing the database off of old wordpress.com entries or deprecated urls
- running debug mode and not getting any logs from the wsod

I of course landed on my self made theme as the issue. I went over the functions.php file to remove and clean up all custom additions that are not necessary for functionality. I used a theme check plugin to help me weed out most of the issues that come from being a beginner at this, but nothing looks to be related at all to backend.

Especially irritating is the part where it works fine for me while using my pc, but any other device, like smartphone, tablet or other pcs can't seem to get into the wp-admin version of the site  while my theme is activated.

P.S.: while the theme is active, backend functionalities like searching for new plugins or changing settings seem to not work right or lead to wsod even for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into a simillar issue, the solution given by online guides always mentions making sure the END of the functions.php file does not have any empty space there, but they neglect to mention that there can't be any empty line anywhere in the whole file, even within the code.